# Changing a foreign key constraint in a Laravel migration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations

I have this migration file

```
Schema::create('table_one', function(Blueprint $table) 
{ 
    $table->increments('id'); 
    $table->string('name'); 
    $table->integer('table_two_id')->unsigned(); 
    $table->foreign('table_two_id')->references('id')->on('table_two'); 
    $table->timestamps(); 
});
```

I want to update to make the foreign key cascade on delete, as though I had run this:

```
$table->foreign('table_two_id')->references('id')->on('table_two')->onDelete('cascade');
```

How can I do this? Is there something like `change()` for foreign keys?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Drop the foreign key then add it again and run migrate.

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('table_one', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign(['table_two_id']);

        $table->foreign('table_two_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('table_two')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Comment: It does make sense, because MySQL would do it the same way, there is no "change" in MySQL for that case. However I expect a wrapper/single_command on Laravel level for a situation like this. Thanks.

Comment: can't delete it if there's data, how can I get the data again? in this case should create a new column then make a script copy the data from the old column to the new one then remove it but it's not the best way to do that, that's my opinion. 

we can install: composer require doctrine/dbal

then change it easily: $table->foreignId('table_two_id')
              ->nullable()->change()

Comment: Wouldn't this be dangerous to run on production?

Answer (score 10):

The Laravel docs says:

> To drop a foreign key, you may use the `dropForeign` method. Foreign key constraints use the same naming convention as indexes. So, **we will concatenate the table name and the columns in the constraint then suffix the name with "_foreign"**:
>
> ```
> $table->dropForeign('posts_user_id_foreign');
> ```
>
> Or, you may pass an array value which will automatically use the conventional constraint name when dropping:
>
> ```
> $table->dropForeign(['user_id']);
> ```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however this naming convention is neither mandatory, nor reliable. I constantly hit the limit of foreign_key_name_length and renaming columns that does not rename dependant foreign keys. So I'm happy with @Borut Flis answer.

Answer (score 5):

1. Run `composer require doctrine/dbal`
2. In your migration file, do this:

   ```
    Schema::table('table_one', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('table_two_id')
              ->change()
              ->constrained('table_two')
              ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
   ```
3. Run `php artisan migrate`

Comment: The error `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1022 Can't write; duplicate key in table...` will raise when updating foreign key by re-defining `constrained`, so just remove the constrained and say something that you only need to update and chain it with `->change()`. In my case I just updated a foreign key to be nullable, I don't need to re-define constrained again because it supposed to be called in the create migration, not the alter one, except you want to change the constrain to another table.

Answer (score 5):

You need to delete the

```
public function up() {
    Schema::table('<tableName>', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('<FK-name>');
        $table->dropColumn('<FK-columnName>');
    });
    Schema::table('<tableName>', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('<FK-columnName>')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
    });
}
```

with two queries.

This is working in Laravel 8