# Update foreign key with migration?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've made a misstake in a migration where I created foreign key and forgot to add onDelete('cascade'), this leads to it being impossible to delete a piece of content that has a foreign relation. Delete fails  due to cascade not being triggered correctly. How do I fix this?

I hoped to do new migration and update foreign key with missing onDelete

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('content_term', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('content_id')->references('id')->on('content')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade')->change();
    });
}
```

But when I try to run it I get this

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1022 Can't write; duplicate key in table '#sql-4688_6b' (SQL: alter table `content_term` add constraint `content_term_content_id_foreign` foreign key (`content_id`) references `content` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade)

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to drop foreign and assign it again, maybe it will help

```php
Schema::table('content_term', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropForeign('content_term_content_id_foreign');
    $table->foreign('content_id')->references('id')->on('content')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

now I've found the similar issue [Laravel :: Best way to update a foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38427672/laravel-best-way-to-update-a-foreign-key)

Comment: If I remove they foreign key I'm afraid I will loose all existing connections? Will that be the case?

Comment: I guess no, anyway you can test it locally. Or duplicate your database in phpmyadmin or what type of database you're using and delete foreign key manually, simply you can do it from phpmyadmin. And you will see what happened, i guess data stored in column will not be removed, just the foreign key will be removed.

Comment: yes everything worked, all conections remained intact. This is indeed a right solution! Thanks Mafftor